# Dynamically creating table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm asking you for help with DOM table in JS. When I click buttons table will be creating automagically with example texts. I want to write a few functions for create table tag, thead, border and align center, caption, data (rows and cells with text), tfoot, deleting row, adding row.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you let us know what you have tried so far? Some code examples would be nice.

Comment: i am sitting on school lesson after month disease and i dont understand how to do this :/ i wrote nothing :(

Comment: Well... stack overflow is here to help you along, not to do your homework for you ;)

Can you use jquery or does it have to be plain javascript?

Comment: plain JS. I know it's not for doing my job, but if you could explain it to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started, you'll have to add the rest of the features yourself.

```js
// get the first button by it's ID, and listen to the click event
// add an empty table to the container div
document.getElementById("btnTable").addEventListener("click", function(){
 var basicTable = '<table id="table"></table>';
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = basicTable;
});

// add contents to the table, ADD instead of REPLACE by using the += operator
document.getElementById("btnTableContentsAdd").addEventListener("click", function(){
 var tableContents = '<tr><td>Hello world!</td></tr>';
  document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += tableContents;
});

// remove last table row
document.getElementById("btnTableContentsRemove").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var lastRow = document.getElementById('table').lastElementChild;
  document.getElementById('table').removeChild(lastRow);
});

// set the border to 1px solid blue
document.getElementById("btnTableBlueBorder").addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById('table').style.border = "1px solid blue";
});

// set the border to 1px solid red
document.getElementById("btnTableRedBorder").addEventListener("click", function(){
 document.getElementById('table').style.border = "1px solid red";
});
```

```html
<button id="btnTable">add empty table (invisible)</button>
<button id="btnTableContentsAdd">add table contents</button>
<button id="btnTableContentsRemove">remove table contents</button>
<button id="btnTableBlueBorder">add blue table border</button>
<button id="btnTableRedBorder">add red table border</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```